# Receiving a 'Map is not a Function' error after upgrading Angular and AngularFireAuth

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularfire2, angular5

I've recently upgraded from Angular 2 to Angular 5, and also updated the AngularFireAuth package.I have run into a problem that I have not been able to figure out.

While I get no compile errors using the .map below I noticed a 'map is not a function' error in the console. Trying to understand what changed from Angular 2 to Angular 5 and what changes I need to use now.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalController } from '../services/globalController.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AngularFireAuth,  private router: Router, private global: GlobalController) { }
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.authState.map(user => {
        if (user && !user.isAnonymous) {
            this.global.setUserEmail(user.email);
            this.global.setUserID(user.uid);
            this.global.setUserName(user.displayName);
            this.global.setUserPhoneNumber(user.phoneNumber);
            if (user.photoURL == null) {
                console.log('No Photo Found.');
                this.global.setUserPhotoLink(this.global.getDefaultPhotoLink());
            }else {
                this.global.setUserPhotoLink(user.photoURL);
            }
            console.log('User Photo Url:' + user.photoURL );
            return true; }
        this.global.ChangeState(this.global.GlobalStates.preLogin);
        return false;
    });
}
```

}

Console Log Error "map is not a function"

```
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: 
  this.authService.authState.map is not a function
  TypeError: this.authService.authState.map is not a function
    at AuthGuard.canActivate (auth-guard.service.ts:14)
at MapSubscriber.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_rxjs_operator_map__.a.call [as project] (router.js:3353)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:69)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:82)
at ArrayObservable._subscribe (ArrayObservable.js:103)
at ArrayObservable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:171)
at ArrayObservable.subscribe (Observable.js:159)
at MapOperator.call (map.js:49)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:156)
at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:78)
at AuthGuard.canActivate (auth-guard.service.ts:14)
at MapSubscriber.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_rxjs_operator_map__
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I also **upgraded RxJS to version ^5.5** and due to the fact that "RxJS is moving to lettable operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators" I need to made modifications to my code to support it.

A good resource can be found [here](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-5/).

In short I modified my import statement from

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

To:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

I also added a .pipe wrapper to the section.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AngularFireAuth,  private router: Router, private global: GlobalController) { }
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.authState.pipe(
         map( user => {
            if (user && !user.isAnonymous) {
                this.global.setUserEmail(user.email);
                this.global.setUserID(user.uid);
                this.global.setUserName(user.displayName);
                this.global.setUserPhoneNumber(user.phoneNumber);
                if (user.photoURL == null) {
                    console.log('No Photo Found.');
                    this.global.setUserPhotoLink(this.global.getDefaultPhotoLink());
                }else {
                    this.global.setUserPhotoLink(user.photoURL);
                }
                console.log('User Photo Url:' + user.photoURL );
                return true; }
            this.global.ChangeState(this.global.GlobalStates.preLogin);
            return false;
    }));
}
```